# What's the best way to use our bathwater to water our garden?

Tags: water, hose

Every year nowadays, we have a heatwave that dries up our garden.

Every morning, I have a shower that uses a whole load of clean water, and still leaves it reasonably clean; clean enough to water the garden, at least.

So, for the last few years, I've tried putting the plug in while I shower and then using our hosepipes to siphon off the water from the bathroom into the garden.  I've tried sucking the water into the pipe; I've tried filling the pipe in the bath, then plugging one end and throwing it out of the window; and I've tried [a small hand pump](https://amzn.eu/d1x6rpC).  Each of these has worked to an extent, but some of them are exhausting and none of them are reliable - by the second day, there's usually a bubble in the hose that stops the siphoning from working.

I've seen [small electric pumps](https://amzn.eu/0hf3lX4) suitable for clearing floods or emptying a water butt, which are at the edge of my budget.  They look like they might be the right tool for this job, but I'm concerned that their cut-off sensors would stop them from emptying the bath.

I guess the right thing to do would be some sort of shunt in our drains and a graywater syste. That sounds expensive, but maybe there's a less expensive way of doing it.

Does anyone have any experience of doing what I'm trying to do?  Are those small pumps the best tool for the job or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe try looking at siphon pumps, some are battery/electric and seem less money.

Comment: Are the waste pipes from the shower/bath/sink visible from the outside of the house?

Comment: An out-of-the-box idea: don't take a shower. Use a songwol towel (feels like sandpaper but boy does it get the dirt off) and use small amounts of water from the tap, with a regular washcloth to rinse. Less than a gallon of water used.

Comment: @Triplefault the idea is to get the water to the garden, not reduce water use.

Comment: If you are going to be doing that you will want to reassess which soaps and shampoos you use. At the very least to ensure that your plants aren't going to get poisoned from them.

Comment: @SolarMike, very true. Thus the "out-of-the-box". "Reduce Re-use Recycle" does include Reduce as well as Re-use.

Comment: "out-of-the-box"   Maybe build an outdoor shower...in or next to the garden?

Comment: You better check local codes to make sure this is legal.

Comment: @BMitch so gravity does not count? Like throwing water out of  the window? Simple technique or too simple for some?

Comment: Be aware that graywater disposal like this is prohibited in many communities, for good reason. It can be quite pollutive.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But after we lived in our current house for a few years we discovered that the bathtub drains into the landscaping. We live in the country on acreage and it drains on a slope so it is all fine. No idea if it is strictly legal but it certainly does no harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want an out-of-the-box solution so I would recommend a [submersible water pump](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G3Z3NJK). Make sure to pick one that can pump the water high enough to go from your tub to the window. Also make sure to use the pump **after** showering to reduce electrocution risk =)

You can have it pump outside to some sort of barrel but it will be important to use the water immediately or else nasty stuff will quickly grow and make the water hazardous.

Do note that gray water is not suitable for root crops. https://www.gardenmyths.com/gray-water-safe-garden/

Additionally, check with your local ordinance about permitted usage/storage of gray water.

You can also consider re-using your laundry machine water as well.

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to make sure that the static head of the pump can make it over your window ledge if you pursue this. For example the pump linked above won't lift water higher than 8". In your case pumping rate will be a secondary issue, and one you probably want a shower pump.

Comment: @user278411 My bad, I wasn't trying to make a specific product model recommendation. Hopefully one of the higher wattage pump choices can handle it. I've edited my answer to reflect your concern though.

Answer (score 4):

You said "best" so I think the best way is going to be to modify your tub's plumbing to direct the waste water from its usual route and instead go to a holding tank of some sort where you can then access the water for your gardening needs.

Answer (score 2):

Get an aquarium or pond pump ( same pump will cost more if named "pond pump"), any size you can imagine, inexpensive on-line, double insulated, submersible, pipe threads or hose barbs. I regularly use one to pump 55 gal rain barrel water; connected to a garden hose. PS : Also great for emptying water from broken clothes washer.